# Split y Join de un texto a palabras respetando los espacios en blanco en Java

Tags: java

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de separar las palabras de un texto que puede contener múltiples espacios en blanco concatenados, tabuladores y saltos de línea?

Procesar el array de palabras y después ajuntarlas, respetando los mismos espacios que hubieran.

Dummy text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor  sit amet, consectetur is adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una manera es con [expresiones regulares con lookahead](http://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-2/)

```
    String[] list = st.split("((?<=\\s)(?!\\s))|((?<!\\s)(?=\\s))");
```

Esto te devolverá un array que altenará delimitadores (blancos) con palabras (no blancos). Su concatenación debería corresponder al string original.

---

Explicación: queremos hacer un split usando un delimitador de "ancho cero" (zero width), correspondiente a cada posicion del string donde haya una transición blanco-no blanco o viceversa.

El [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) consta del "OR" de estas dos posibilidades : `"( )|( )"`

La primera mitad `(?<=\\s)(?!\\s)` consiste en: primero, `?<=` indica un "look behind" (mirar atrás) positivo, y el pattern `\\s` es un blanco; entonces, esto matcheará cuando "atrás" (a la izquierda de la posición actual) haya un blanco. Después tengo `?!`, un "look ahead" (mirar adelante) negativo, con el mismo pattern; esto matcheará cuando "adelante" (a la derecha de la posición actual) NO tenga un blanco.

La segunda mitad es, a la inversa, un look behind negativo  seguido de un look ahead positivo (no-blanco seguido de blanco).

Los paréntesis internos son requeridos por la sintaxis de look-ahead, look-behind. Los externos agrupan lo que va en el OR.

Comment: Probare de implementar tu solución, por lo que me comentas de los tabs, y para ajuntarlo Array.tostring(list)?

Comment: Para concatenar el array:  `String.join("", list)`  (solo en Java 8)

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución

Para separar las palabras y que se mantenga los multiples espacios en blanco

```
String[] words = str.split(" ");
```

Y para ajuntar uso la siguiente función:

```
public static String join(String r[],String d) {
    if (r.length == 0) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<r.length-1;i++)
        sb.append(r[i]).append(d);
    return sb.toString()+r[i];
}
```

Su uso

```
String str = join(words, " ");
```

Las pruebas que he realizado, respecta la cadena inicial.

**Update**

Solución basada en la respuesta de @Leonbloy

```
String str = "Lorem ipsum    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\n Fusce erat mau[ris], pretium sed metus in, efficitur\n\nultima.";
```

Para separar las palabras, teniendo en cuenta, tabuladores y saltos de linea.

```
String[] list = str.split("((?<=\\s)(?!\\s))|((?<!\\s)(?=\\s))");
```

Para ajuntar el array String hacia un String

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : list) {
    builder.append(s);
}
String endStr =  builder.toString();

System.out.println(endStr);
```

Comment: El problema con esto es que por "espacios en blanco" solo aceptas el caracter de espacio `' '`  (no tabs, por ejemplo). Además, por supuesto, si el split se hizo es para trabajar con cada "segmento" (blancos, palabras) por separado, no sirve mucho (`words` también contiene blancos si la cadena original contiene blancos seguidos)